# Facebook comment box not working

Tags: facebook, button, comments, box

**I have two problems with my facebook comment box:**

- One is that when I post a comment, I can't view that comment from a different account.
- The second problem is that my comment box looks different to the most other. For example the "Add comment" button and the number of posts (which should be at the top of the comment box) are missing. Also there is a button missing that says something like "show more comments" at the bottom of the comment box.

What I have done so far:

- I have already made my Facebook App
- I have placed the SDK with my App_ID
- I have placed the code for the facebook comment box

Here's a pic of my comment box as it looks so far

[image]

I have googled this problem so many times but there was nothing helpful and I really want to solve this problem. I'd appreciate every tip!

Answer (score 1):

For point 1: I post a comment, I can't view that comment from a different account

- Only approved comments can be view by other users on particular post

For Point 2: Also there is a button missing that says something like "show more comments"

- In comment box you have to provides "Number of Posts" to display, after reaching this limit it will display "view more comments" button at bottom
- When you are logged in and posting any comments, it will not display "view more" comments button for your not approved comments

Answer (score 0):

first create your app and use js code as facebook provide. and use that code as they mentions.

for ex. . place the below code after body tag.  only replace the app id.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

after that the configration code of ur comment box should be like this.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href=" here is ur page url link" data-width="500" data-numposts="3" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

paste above code below  your page..

thats all... done.